# Question title capitalization convention

Tags: discussion

So I've been wondering whether it's better to capitalize all the words in the title for example

### 1. "This is a Title that has Capitalized Words."

*or* just capitalize the first word as used in normal sentences..

### 2. "This is a title that has regular capitalization in it's name."

I've been capitalizing every word in the title. Here's my argument for that. Although most questions are titled in the matter of #2, I think #1 is generally used on most news sites. Therefore, I think it looks more professional.

However, I would like to hear what the majority of people think about this. How should we capitalize question titles?

Answer (score 10):

This has been asked over on the [SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98066/capitalizing-titles) and [EL&U](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1992/how-should-titles-be-capitalized) meta sites.

In short, Stack Exchange sites use sentence case because:

- Question 'titles' are not titles in every context
- Sentence case is more readable, particularly in lists (see the related questions on the right)

Comment: both good points.